# PySide/PyQT signals and slots with tuples?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

The [PySide docs](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) that talk about signals and slots give examples of signals that are `str` and `int` types. What do you do if you want the signals to be a pair of ints in a tuple?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `object` to pass a tuple.

For example:

```
signal = Signal(object)
signal.connect(...)
signal.emit(tuple)
```

Comment: what does the type parameter actually do, anyway?

Comment: @JasonS I'm not entirely sure since I'm not too familiar with the internals of PySide or QT, but this seems to dive into how signals and slots work a little bit: http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PySide, only PyQt, but you should also be able to use `Signal(tuple)`. Without knowing the details: the need for this come from the fact that PySide & PyQt wrap the underlying C++ signals. The type parameter also allows to implement one signal with multiple signatures, such as http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#activated.

Comment: @sebastian For anyone wondering, this fails with a `TypeError: C++ type 'tuple' is not supported as a slot argument type`. It seems the only solution  (at least in PyQt) is to use `QtCore.SIGNAL("signal_name(PyQt_PyObject)")`.

Comment: @ThibaudRuelle I cannot reproduce this error message. I can define and use a `pyqtSignal(tuple)` as well as a `pyqtSlot(tuple)` just fine ... on PyQt 4.11.3 that is.

Comment: @sebastian I obtained the error using old-style signals (`QtCore.SIGNAL("signal_name(tuple)")`). Looks like the new-style `pyqtSignal()` function fixed this, good to know.